# Any alternate tools or trick to insert data in Oracle database through Microsoft SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have only MSSQL script file with schema and data. I want to add all schema and data in Oracle database table. I am looking for some of the best way to do this. Because MSSQL script file contain thousands of record and it's mostly time consume to convert manual for Oracle (Lots of datatype changes).

If any tools to convert MSSQL script for Oracle DB then please suggest me.

Also any alternate option for MSSQL script execute on Oracle DB then please let me know. I know MSSQL and Oracle DB have lots of datatype difference and directly not possible to execute MSSQL script in Oracle.

I am using Oracle XE (Express edition).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am still looking for best solution. If someone can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of tools to cross migrate the schema. I would suggest to use Talend tool for your migration. Talend in basically an ETL tool, below are the functionalities useful for you,

1. You can migrate DDL's as Talend itself manages to convert to respective database
2. You can also move all the data from Sql-server to Oracle